# htaccess rewriterule syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .htaccess, iis-7, .net-3.5

I want to redirect any url that ends with

`../Toolbar/Promote/Default.aspx`

to

`/distributionTools`

I have tried

`RewriteRule ^/Toolbar/Promote/Default.aspx$ /distributionTools [NC,L,R=301]`

but http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ show this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `RewriteRule` seems to do what you want:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)Toolbar/Promote/Default.aspx$ /distributionTools [NC,L,R=301]`

It matches any URI that ends with `Toolbar/Promote/Default.aspx` and redirects to `distributionTools`.

Please note that `(.*)` is important, without it it will redirect foo.com/**bar/baz**/Toolsbar/Promote/Default.aspx to foo.com/**bar/baz**/distributionTools`, which is probably not what you expect.

Comment: thanks, though I see matching `Toolbar/Promote/Default.aspx` is case sensetive. How can it be non-case sensitive? I thought it was the `NC` flag

Comment: @EladBenda: yes, this is what the `NC` flag is for. The matching has to be case-insensitive, but I'm not sure whether  htaccess.madewithlove.be properly supports flags or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net 4.0 you can do this at application level by using your Global.asax file in the route of your .net project.

Simply add the following code to it if not already present:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   // This is the new URL ROuting option in .NET 4
    RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.MapPageRoute("Distribution", "/distributionTools", "~/Toolbar/Promote/Default.aspx");
}
```

I hope this helps!